# System error dialog box keeps popping up

Tags: 12.04, software-center

Randomly when I am using my computer a dialog pops up saying "Ubuntu 12.04 has found an error in your system. Would you like to report it?" and also often times my applications just randomly close. I am not sure if they are corolated. I just got ubuntu on this computer yesterday so I don't think that I could have screwed up yet. When I click on more details it says that it has to do with some gnome-control-center thing. Also my computer is not letting me download any packages. It just says that it has failed whether I do it with sudo apt-get or with Ubuntu software center.

Thanks in Advance,

Eli

Comment: The pop up says: **System Problem detected** Cancel or Report now

Comment: Now It is not letting me even open ubuntu software center. Whenever I try, it opens for a second then closes and opens the dialog. PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 0):

open terminal CTRL +ALT + T

then write

nano /var/log/syslog

(location of your systems error logs)
Find the time stamp, when these errors occur and paste it here.

Comment: Everything has the same stamp

Comment: The stam is _16:21:36_